# Eigendecomposition Formula Structure

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm just learning the ropes of linear algebra right now and I'm confused about the intuition behind eigendecomposition.

As I understand it so far, the formula $$A=V\text{diag}(\lambda)V^{-1}$$
represents an alternative way of describing the transformation applied by $A$ in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, moving right to left, and using a hypothetical vector $v$, the transformation $V^{-1}$ is applied first to $v$, followed by a scaling using $\text{diag}(\lambda)$, then reverted using $V$.

Why is it not $V^{-1}diag(\lambda)V$, where we first translate $v$ to the basis vectors of the eigenvector matrix, apply the scaling, and then 'undoing' the basis change using $V^{-1}$?

Comment: @kipf thank you so much, that has clarified things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a basic example: Take the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ in the standard basis. Suppose we want to find the matrix $A$ that we can use to get the representation in the new basis $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} \right\}$.

The target is the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. See which one of $\begin{bmatrix}1& 1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ (the inverse) gets you the desired outcome.

I will admit, this is not the best answer, there is probably a logical theoretical justification that is escaping me at the moment, perhaps someone can elaborate on that.

What I can do is provide an alternative view: Let your distinct eigenvalues be $\lambda_i$, with corresponding eigenvectors $v_i$. We get the equations $Av_i=\lambda_i v_i$. We can put all these equations together and write it in matrix form to get

$A\begin{bmatrix}v_1& v_2&\cdots&v_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1v_1& \lambda_2v_2&\cdots&\lambda_nv_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1& v_2&\cdots&v_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1& 0& \cdots& 0\\
0& \lambda_2& \cdots & 0\\
\vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots\\ 0& 0& \cdots& \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$

$\implies A=V\text{diag}(\lambda)V^{-1}$